# php array_multisort sorting columns i didnt ask to be sorted

Tags: php, sorting

i am sorting a multidimensional array by one of the columns using array_multisort.  yes, i know this function is not needed to sort by only one column, but this is for code where there could be more columns being sorted on and right now only the one test is failing.

when i run a test i found on the interwebs, it works fine.  when i run pretty much the exact same thing with some other test data, it is ALSO sorting on a column i didnt ask it to sort on.

This test returns proper sorted data (value NOT sorted):

```
$vc_array = array (
0 => array ('id' => 1,'name' => 'xyz','value' => 'abc','order' => 6),
 1 => array ('id' => 2,'name' => 'abc','value' => 'xyz','order' => 2),
 2 => array ('id' => 3,'name' => 'uvw','value' => 'ghi','order' => 1),
 3 => array ('id' => 4,'name' => 'def','value' => 'xyz','order' => 2,),
 4 => array ('id' => 5,'name' => 'ghi','value' => 'uvw','order' => 3),
 5 => array ('id' => 6,'name' => 'ghi','value' => 'def','order' => 3),
 6 => array ('id' => 7,'name' => 'ghi','value' => 'fff','order' => 3)
);

$vc_array_name = array_column($vc_array, 'name');

$out = array_multisort($vc_array_name, SORT_ASC, $vc_array);

var_dump($vc_array); // note the name 'ghi' and the order of the 'value' column.  the 'value' column has NOT been sorted, which is what is expected.
```

Dumped data:

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(3) "abc" ["value"]=> string(3) "xyz" ["order"]=> int(2) } [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(3) "def" ["value"]=> string(3) "xyz" ["order"]=> int(2) } [2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> string(3) "ghi" ["value"]=> string(3) "uvw" ["order"]=> int(3) } [3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["name"]=> string(3) "ghi" ["value"]=> string(3) "def" ["order"]=> int(3) } [4]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(3) "ghi" ["value"]=> string(3) "fff" ["order"]=> int(3) } [5]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["name"]=> string(3) "uvw" ["value"]=> string(3) "ghi" ["order"]=> int(1) } [6]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["name"]=> string(3) "xyz" ["value"]=> string(3) "abc" ["order"]=> int(6) } }
```

This test sorts properly on the 'name' field, but is also sorting on the 'quantity' field which i did NOT request, and do not want that column to be sorted:

```
$objectListData4 =  [
        ["name" => "package", "quantity" => 1000, "color" => "brown"],
        ["name" => "box", "quantity" => 1000, "color" => "red"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 250, "color" => "orange"],
        ["name" => "pencil", "quantity" => 100, "color" => "yellow"],
        ["name" => "bag", "quantity" => 150, "color" => "blue"],
        ["name" => "box", "quantity" => 1200, "color" => "pink"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 50, "color" => "blue"],
        ["name" => "package", "quantity" => 1500, "color" => "green"],
        ["name" => "bag", "quantity" => 500, "color" => "green"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 100, "color" => "yellow"],
    ];

$tmp = array_column($objectListData4, 'name');
array_multisort($tmp, SORT_ASC, $objectListData4);

var_dump($objectListData4); // note the name 'notebook' and the order of the 'quantity' column.  the 'quantity' column has also been sorted but shouldnt be
```

Dumped data:

```
array(10) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "bag" ["quantity"]=> int(150) ["color"]=> string(4) "blue" } [1]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "bag" ["quantity"]=> int(500) ["color"]=> string(5) "green" } [2]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "box" ["quantity"]=> int(1000) ["color"]=> string(3) "red" } [3]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(3) "box" ["quantity"]=> int(1200) ["color"]=> string(4) "pink" } [4]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "notebook" ["quantity"]=> int(50) ["color"]=> string(4) "blue" } [5]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "notebook" ["quantity"]=> int(100) ["color"]=> string(6) "yellow" } [6]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "notebook" ["quantity"]=> int(250) ["color"]=> string(6) "orange" } [7]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(7) "package" ["quantity"]=> int(1000) ["color"]=> string(5) "brown" } [8]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(7) "package" ["quantity"]=> int(1500) ["color"]=> string(5) "green" } [9]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "pencil" ["quantity"]=> int(100) ["color"]=> string(6) "yellow" } }
```

Can anyone see why the second test is also sorting the quantity when it shouldnt be??

Comment: This is documented behaviour. In the manual, for the first example, it states *"The entries in the second array corresponding to the identical entries in the first array (100 and 100) were sorted as well"*. In your case, that would be the entries in the second array `$objectListData4` corresponding to the identical `"notebook"` values in the first array `$tmp`.

Comment: there is no "100" in the first array.  the first array contains only the key and name and thats it - no quantity.

Comment: The quote is referring to the example arrays, the first of which does have values of "100". In your case that is equivalent to the first array having multiple "notebook" values and the second array then being sorted on quantity. @GeorgeAppleton answer is correct and you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the cause for your error is, I suspect it's undocumented functionality that array_multisort sorts arrays of arrays by looking for the next available associative key or something.

But a solution to make sure no further sorting will take place is to pass in the array keys as the 2nd sort parameter. Working version of your second given example:

```
$objectListData4 =  [
        ["name" => "package", "quantity" => 1000, "color" => "brown"],
        ["name" => "box", "quantity" => 1000, "color" => "red"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 250, "color" => "orange"],
        ["name" => "pencil", "quantity" => 100, "color" => "yellow"],
        ["name" => "bag", "quantity" => 150, "color" => "blue"],
        ["name" => "box", "quantity" => 1200, "color" => "pink"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 50, "color" => "blue"],
        ["name" => "package", "quantity" => 1500, "color" => "green"],
        ["name" => "bag", "quantity" => 500, "color" => "green"],
        ["name" => "notebook", "quantity" => 100, "color" => "yellow"],
    ];

$tmp = array_column($objectListData4, 'name');
array_multisort($tmp, SORT_ASC, array_keys($objectListData4), $objectListData4);

var_dump($objectListData4); // note the name 'notebook' and the order of the 'quantity' column.  the 'quantity' column has also been sorted but shouldnt be
```

And it's output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bag"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(150)
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bag"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(500)
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "box"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "box"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1200)
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "pink"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "notebook"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(250)
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "orange"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "notebook"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(50)
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "notebook"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(100)
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "yellow"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "package"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "package"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(1500)
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "pencil"
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(100)
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "yellow"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does fix it in this specific case.  Tho not knowing what is causing it to do unrequested secondary sorting on one dataset but not another makes me wonder if this fix fixes it in every case, or if its going to be seemingly random still.  And not knowing whats causing the original issue makes me wonder if this is ONLY an issue sometimes when there is only one column being sorted on, or if it can happen when there are more than 1.  Would need to dig into the internals of php to find out.

Comment: It will fix it in any case, the code I added effectively disables further secondary sorting. Just put your sort array before and the array to be sorted after

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093664/how-php-array-multisort-work) question can help you, on the other hand, maybe usort() is a choice

```
usort($objectListData4, 'cmp');

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot use array_multisort() to achieve what you want because if two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined. (See the note in http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

It means you cannot expect your "notebooks" to preserve their original order. If they happened to do it, it was just a coincidence.

Here is one solution for you.

```
function jnlsort($a, $b)//if the names are same, sort by index. Otherwise, sort by name.
{
    if (($a['name'] == $b['name']))
    {
        return strcmp($a['index'], $b['index']);
    }

    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

foreach($objectListData4 as $index => $obj)//add the index fields to preserve the order
{
    $objectListData4[$index]["index"] = $index;
}

usort($objectListData4, 'jnlsort');

foreach($objectListData4 as $index => $obj)//remove the index fields
{
    unset($objectListData4[$index]["index"]);
}
```